# how to execute a code based on some ratio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, performance

I know the heading might not give you a clarity . let me  explain here

I have a test case (load testing) in visual studio.The requirement is, it has to access different url based on the allocation which is given in the web.config file.

In web.config I have a set of value

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Allocation1" value="20"/>
<add key="Allocation2" value="80"/>
</appSettings>
```

While running the test I want to access the 1st url 20% and 2nd url 80%. Means if the first url selected 2 times then next 8 times 2nd url should be selected .

can anyone have a clue that , is that achievable? any leads ?

Comment: `Means if the first url selected 2 times then next 8 times 2nd url should be selected .` What should happen after that?

Comment: after that i have a code which will do rest of the functionality. now random selection of url and rest functionalities are  working fine.

Comment: What are you having a problem with specifically? Reading from the config file? Running some code X times (but that's just a `for loop` right?) something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of iterations, I would implement it based on random values. Basically

1. Generate a random number between, let's say, 0 and 100:

   ```
   var rnd = new Random();
   var number = rnd.Next(0, 100);
   ```
2. Check whether the number is above or below your first threshold

   ```
   if(number <= allocation1)
       [[call URL 1]];
   else
       [[call URL 2]];
   ```

If your number of iterations is large enough, this will converge to an 80/20 distribution of calls to URL 2. Obviously, if you just use, let's say, 10 iterations, this won't be very accurate. If you have such a low number of iterations, use a variable that tracks the percentage of calls to URL 1 and URL 2. If the percentage surpasses 20%, call only the second URL until the percentage drops below 20% again

```
var percentage = callsToUrl1 / totalCalls;
if(percentage > 0.2)
    [[call URL 2]];
else
    [[use the normal random algorithm as above]];
```

EDIT:
For more than two percentages, use more conditions

```
if(number <= allocation1)
    [[call URL 1]];
else if(number <= allocation1 + allocation2)
    [[call URL 2]];
else
    [[call URL 3]];
```

and so on..

Comment: While I agree with the law of large numbers, there seems to be little reason to introduce randomization here. OP is trying to execute a _specific_ distribution. Randomization will, at best, not significantly change the distribution. But it has a chance to do so, at worst.

Comment: @leonard_deutsch , ok here what will be the result if I am giving 3 values instead of 2  .. like    30%,30%,40%